# layout qualifier name mix layout-w1024dp

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I used this name for my folder and it worked :
layout-w1024dp-land

I wonder if I could mix it with old qualifiers : ldpi | mdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi | tvdpi

layout-w1024dp-land-mdpi

layout-w1024dp-port-hdpi

layout-w1024dp-port-xhdpi

Does it work like this ? Could I mix those qualifiers ?

PS : If I know the density in xml, I know home and back button height. No calculations are necessary.

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: It worked. That's perfect :)